# Upload APK file via Gradle/Groovy Multipart Request task

Tags: gradle, groovy, multipart, gradle-task

I'm trying to implement a gradle task to upload an APK file to my web service using `http-builder-ng`. I'm struggling with the encoding part.

An APK file effectively is a ZIP format file, so I tried using the content type `application/zip` but it's not recognized by the encoders provided:

```
task publish(...) {
   // ...
   post {
        request.contentType = 'multipart/form-data'
        request.encoder 'multipart/form-data', OkHttpEncoders.&multipart
        request.body = multipart {
            part 'file', 'myApp.apk', 'application/zip', new File(System.getProperty('user.dir'), 'myApp.apk')
        }
        response.success { fs, content ->
            prinln "success"
        }
    }
}
```

The error message is following:
`Could not find encoder for content-type (application/zip)`

Can anybody help me which encoder to use and how?